# How to use Server-Sent Events HTML 5 to create an image gallery

Tags: php, html, canvas, server-sent-events

I would like to create a full screen image playlist that rotates images from a folder in the web server.

If I put in a new images the browser will automatically put the new image up for rotation, same case if I remove the image it should remove the image from rotation.

What technology or plugins can I use to create something like this?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: js, jquery, maybe some css 3 effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three technologies, that might be interesting for you:

- Long Polling Ajax Request: These work pretty good with all up to date browsers. The idea is, to keep an ajax request open till something changes. Be carefull with the web server you are using - if it uses a fixed number of threats these might pretty fast be exhaustet.
- Server Send Events: The Client opens a http connection and the server send events to the clients over this one connection. There isn't a broad support for this technology in frameworks and in browsers (like IE10).
- WebSockets: This is the newest technology for pushing events to the client. The Clients opens an http connection to the server. After that, a protocol change is done and both sides can send even binary data. There is a broad support for this in up to date browsers - including IE10. You might still run into problems with proxy servers.

Besides these three technologies, you can still poll the server using an ajax request every couple of seconds or minutes. This might be sufficcient, if there is no need for real-/ near-time.

Comment: Thanks! I will built this application for internal use so it doesnt matter the browser penetration rate. I can easily install chrome or something else other than IE. I want to create a system where I can play video/images on the browser side with me able to pushmore content to the browser to display. Which of the three technologies do you think suits this purpose

Comment: Under these circumstances, i think WebSockets are the appropriate solution.